# Both TableViews showing same data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I am using two `UITableView` in same `View`. I have used prototype cell in which there are two `label` to show date and venue in `TableView`.
Here is the code what I did. Both `TableViews` showing same data.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


UITableView *tableViewOne=(UITableView*)[self.view viewWithTag:5];
UITableView *tableViewtwo=(UITableView*)[self.view viewWithTag:6];



UITableViewCell *cell;


if (tableViewOne) {
    NSLog(@"In Table1");
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
   cell=[tableViewOne dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    UILabel * dateLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:111];
    dateLabel.text = [dateArrayLableInTableviewOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *venueLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:114];
    venueLabel.text=[venueArrayLabelInTableViewOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}

  else if(tableViewtwo){
    NSLog(@"In Tabl2 ");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"cellTwo";

    cell = [tableViewtwo dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

        }


      UILabel * dateLabelOfTableViewTwo = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:211];
      dateLabelOfTableViewTwo.text = [dateArrayLabelInTableViewTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      UILabel *venueLabelOfTableViewTwo=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:214];
      venueLabelOfTableViewTwo.text=[venueArrayLabelInTableViewTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}


 return cell;
```

}

Comment: Your `if` comparison is incorrect. It should be something like `if (tableView == tableViewOne)`.

Comment: you can use if (self.tableView.tag == yourtag) instead of self.view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **if** condition is incorrect. So please check like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell;


if (tableView.tag == 5) // Change here 
{
    NSLog(@"In Table1");
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
   cell=[tableViewOne dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    UILabel * dateLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:111];
    dateLabel.text = [dateArrayLableInTableviewOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *venueLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:114];
    venueLabel.text=[venueArrayLabelInTableViewOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}

  else
{
    NSLog(@"In Tabl2 ");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"cellTwo";

    cell = [tableViewtwo dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

        }


      UILabel * dateLabelOfTableViewTwo = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:211];
      dateLabelOfTableViewTwo.text = [dateArrayLabelInTableViewTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      UILabel *venueLabelOfTableViewTwo=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:214];
      venueLabelOfTableViewTwo.text=[venueArrayLabelInTableViewTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}


 return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like

```
if (tableView == tableViewOne){

      // Your Code
}

elseif (tableView == tableViewTwo){

      // Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your comaprison is incorrect since both table view are present, first condition get satisfied always thus same data in both tables.

Compare using UITableView object identifiers

```
if (tableView==first_table_view_name) {
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


    //UITableView *tableViewOne=(UITableView*)[self.view viewWithTag:5];
    //UITableView *tableViewtwo=(UITableView*)[self.view viewWithTag:6];



    UITableViewCell *cell;


    if (tableView.tag==5) // problem is here
{
        NSLog(@"In Table1");
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
       cell=[tableViewOne dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        UILabel * dateLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:111];
        dateLabel.text = [dateArrayLableInTableviewOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel *venueLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:114];
        venueLabel.text=[venueArrayLabelInTableViewOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    }

      else if(tableView.tag==6){
        NSLog(@"In Tabl2 ");
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"cellTwo";

        cell = [tableViewtwo dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

            }


          UILabel * dateLabelOfTableViewTwo = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:211];
          dateLabelOfTableViewTwo.text = [dateArrayLabelInTableViewTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

          UILabel *venueLabelOfTableViewTwo=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:214];
          venueLabelOfTableViewTwo.text=[venueArrayLabelInTableViewTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }


     return cell;

    }
```